# Select empty space and change color in vector

Tags: adobe-illustrator, path, fill

I have a vector which has some empty regions. I am not sure how to fill some specific empty regions since I can't make a selection, and also the 'image trace' is disabled. 
In this example, I want to make the pole red.

I am a newbie in AI.

The .ai file can be found here: [vector_problem.ai](https://github.com/WELZ-gh/Drafts/raw/master/Saved/vector_problem.ai)

[image]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can select your path and **Right click → Release Compound Path** (<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>8</kbd>).

This will break away the cutout back to it's own shape which can then be filled.

[image: releasing compound path and filling individual paths]

Comment: yes yes yes great stuff!!

Comment: which software did you use to produce that gif?

Comment: [ScreenToGif](https://www.screentogif.com/), I love it, it's really awesome and easy!